# Is I need to translate my store listing in to region specified language?

Tags: android, localization, google-play, publish, google-translate

I am a android game publisher on Google play. I usually use Google translate to translate my store listing text into multi-language. I write the source text by hand and then use GG translate. When I meet something like English (US) - English(UK), Spanish(Spanish) - Spanish(US).... I know US Spanish is a little different form Spanish Spanish, but it's 90% similar so I accept the different. In google translate, it's have only Spanish, so I used that Spanish version for both Spanish(Spanish) - Spanish(US) in my store listing. It seem to be too time consuming. Can I just use Spanish (Spanish) in my store-listing and don't add translation for Spanish(US)? If a customer who using Spanish US, can he see my store listing text in Spanish? Say another way, does it necessary for add many translations for one language (Spanish/ Portuguese) but for many country (Spanish, US, Brazil,...)?

Answer (score 0):

Translation is not necessary. But it makes your app user friendly. I think in your case it fine to simplify translation.

As a user I'm dislike applications which use low quality translations by Google Translate to my native language (Russian) and seams like not check result. It looks ugly. Correct English it's even better than bad translation.